# My redhat setup usb stucks on "[Finished] - Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen" I tried to reinstall the iso and wrote it again over again but it is same

Tags: linux, rhel, boot, installer-anaconda

1. I am trying it on hp-dbxxxx
2. I installed it over and over again. So don't ask me about it.
3. I had some conversations with Red Hat support technicians. They didn't help.

Comment: I already telled the computer model. It just stucks and doesn't go further. What else can i say?